# What is the shortest way to count prime numbers from an array. All normal primality test are not passing the test cases because of time limit

Tags: c

The code given below passes two test cases and sieve of eratosthenes passes 1 test case. How can this problem be solved.

I have already tried miller rabin and sieve eratosthenes primality test.
None is passing all the test cases because of time restriction. Is there any possible way faster than these?
The below code is passing two of the 5 test cases. Can it be made any shorter in terms of time complexity?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int isPrime(int n) 
{
    int i;
    int x=(int)(sqrt(n));
    if(n==2)
    return 1;
    else if(n%2==0)
    return 0;
    else
    {
        for(i=3;i<=x;i+=2)
        {
            if(n%i==0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;

}
int counting(int *a,int n)
{
    int i,c=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(isPrime(a[i]))
        c++;
    }
    return c;
}
void main()
{
    int cases,n,a[100000],i,j,count;
    scanf("%d",&cases);
    for(i=0;i<cases;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        scanf("%d",&a[j]);
        count=counting(a,n);

        printf("%d\n",count);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use the sieve of Eratosthenes to build a cached set of primes. Build it just up to the number in question, and extend it later if necessary. If you don't have enough memory for all numbers used so far, store only the primes. Then search the list by `bsearch()`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try this algorithm, i got from this [site](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/prime-number). It seems to be more time-efficient:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int n, i, flag = 0;
        printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for(i = 2; i <= n/2; ++i)
        {
            // condition for nonprime number
            if(n%i == 0)
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (n == 1) 
        {
          printf("1 is neither a prime nor a composite number.");
        }
        else 
        {
            if (flag == 0)
              printf("%d is a prime number.", n);
            else
              printf("%d is not a prime number.", n);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This algorithm is considerably slower than the one in the question for any significant value of `n` — measurable from about 1000, probably even before that.